# 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'username'

Tags: python, flask

When testing this code i get the error "400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'username'" and i cant figure out why

Here is the code, i am using flask to do this

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
if 'username' in session:
    username = session['username']
    return 'Logged in as ' + username + '<br>' + \
     "<b><a href = '/logout'>click here to log out</a></b>"
return  "You are not logged in <br><a href = '/login'></b>" + \
  "click here to log in</b></a>"

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'POST':
    session['username'] = request.form['username']
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
return '''

<form action = "" method = "post">
<p><input type = text name = username/></p>
<p><input type = submit value = Login /></p>
</form>

'''
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
#remove the session from username if it is there
session.pop('username', None)
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

Comment: Why do you not put any `"` in around the values (like "username") in your html code?

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error because there's no key `username`, most likely in the `request.form` object inside the `if request.method == 'POST'` block. This may be because of the way you're creating the form in HTML. You should put quotes around the field attributes, like:

```
<form action="" method="post">
<p><input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Login"/></p>
</form>
```

Comment: This worked, thank you so much, turns out it was just me not looking hard enough